# News Notification in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

I am working on app in which i need to implement a functionality of **News Notification**.

For example, **The NDTV news app**: it gives notification whenever there is new news. How does it happen?

Could anyone provide me a solution example?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You will have to read the rss feed and then show the notification accordingly

Comment: Thanks for reply Auto-Droid. In my case i need to push data from web service. The notification will occur in a fixed interval. Any Example will be appreciated.

Comment: Create pending intent in android, start services at certain intervals, check if there is new news and display in your notification

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
    private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String appname = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    Notification notification;
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, myactivity.class), 0);

    // To support 2.3 os, we use "Notification" class and 3.0+ os will use
    // "NotificationCompat.Builder" class.
    if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        notification = new Notification(icon, message, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, appname, message,
                contentIntent);
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

    } else {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context);
        notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
                .setContentText(message).build();

        notificationManager.notify((int) when , notification);

    }

}
```